# Retrieving user by ID, iOS Chat SDK

Tags: quickblox

I am trying to integrate Quickblox into my app, my user IDs are matching Quickblox user IDs, so when I'm on a some user's page, I know his ID and I need to retrieve this user from Quickblox database, set him as an opponent and initialize Chat with this opponent. Unfortunately, I can not retrieve this through QBUsers userWithID call (recieving errors in delegate). Could you, please, privide a simple example of retrieving user by ID and setting him as opponent. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

1) Connect your user to QuickBlox user. QuickBlox user has **externalUserID** field, so set your system user id to this field

```
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.login = @"iostest3355";
user.password = @"iostest3355";
user.externalUserID = 46732; // you system user id

[QBUsers signUp:user delegate:self];
```

2) Next, you have your system user id, you need to retrieve QuickBlox user

```
[QBUsers userWithExternalID:46732 delegate:self];

 - (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
     if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBUUserResult.class]){
          QBUUserResult *res = (QBUUserResult *)result;
          int qbUserID = res.user.ID;
     }
}
```

3) Use **qbUserID** to chatting